# How to return JsonResponse in Django generic ListView

Tags: django

I'm having trouble returning a valid `HttpResponse` in my `ListView` (and am getting a `ValueError: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object...`. I've overridden `get` because I want to return a JsonResponse:

```
def get(self, requets, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset)
    return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

I've checked that `queryset` and `data` and the `JsonResponse` are not `None`.
Changing the return statement doesn't work:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json", status=200)
```

Previously, if I ever needed to override `get`, I would `return render(...)`, which works.

So, why is my `HttpResponse` or `JsonResponse` not an acceptable HttpResponse as per the error in this instance? The GET request will be an ajax request, and I do need to provide some sensible json in reply.

Edit: full class

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class AjaxQuestionList(ListView):
    """
    Generic ListView for Question objects. Called by front-end app.
    Requires hash url parameter to identify Survey.
    Intended to be called via ajax. Returns serialized json list of Questions.
    """
    http_method_names = ['get',]

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #allow user to call this View if their Client owns the Survey
        self.survey = get_object_or_404(Survey, hash=self.kwargs['hash'])
        up = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, fk_user=self.request.user)
        self.client = up.fk_client
        if self.survey.fk_client != self.client:
            raise Http404
        super(AjaxQuestionList, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(fk_survey=self.survey)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset)
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

Traceback:

> File
>   "/webapps/escher/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/webapps/escher/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _legacy_get_response
>     249.             response = self._get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/webapps/escher/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     198.                 "returned None instead." % (callback.**module**, view_name)
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /si/survey/123456789/ajax-question-list/
>   Exception Value: The view myapp.views.survey.AjaxQuestionList
>   didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

From the [CBV flattened index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#list-views) I just assumed that `render_to_response()` was called automatically after `get()`, rendering whatever HttpResponse `get()` returned. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Please show the stack trace, the code you've shown shouldn't produce that error

Comment: Also please show the full view class.

Comment: Class and traceback added!

Comment: Note that `render_to_response` is called *by* `get()`,  not after. Since you have override `get()`, `render_to_response` will not be called. However, that is ok in your case, because you want to return json instead of rendering a template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the result of `super()` in your dispatch method.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ... 
    return super(AjaxQuestionList, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Without the return statement, the method returns `None` so you get the error message.

Comment: *cries*. I've been staring at this code for the past half hour wondering what it was and all along I forgot the `return`. Thanks Alasdair.